# Pandas problem, 0 transformed to NaN when use "where" method

Tags: python, pandas, int, where-clause, nan

I'm facing a problem i don't understand :

```
>>> Y.isnull().values.any()
False
>>> Y.where(Y == 0).isnull().values.any()
True
```

I don't understand how NaN values can appeared in the second result.
Y has a dtype = int64

Any idea ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the behavior of `pandas.DataFrame.where`:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html

It substitutes the values that don't meet the condition with something. By default that something is not boolean values, it's `1` and `nan`. Which means by doing `Y.where(Y == 0)` you're creating `nan` values instead of all the values that weren't 0. Hence `nan` values in the second line.

Comment: Oh brilliant! I did not understand that "where" behaved like a mask. Thank you!